# discord.py send link by user argument

Tags: discord.py

So I'm trying to make a command for my **discord.py** bot that searches up cosmetics for **fortnite** but it gives me this error:

> h:\alles\Discord Server\bot\msk bot.py:406: SyntaxWarning: 'str'
> object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
> "https://fnbr.co/outfit/" (message),

This is my code:

```
async def skin(ctx, message):  
    await ctx.send(
        "https://fnbr.co/outfit/" (message),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You just messed up the syntax a bit (as the error says). The proper way would either be this:

```py
await ctx.send("https://fnbr.co/outfit/" + message)
```

Or you can use f-strings if you have Python 3.6 or above installed:

```py
await ctx.send(f"https://fnbr.co/outfit/{message}")
```